# RestSharp Missing after Nuget install

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, nuget, restsharp, ssis-2012

I've got a project involving downloading student test scores from a testing vendor to be loaded into our districts scores reporting database. I've used Postman to identify the parameters to send to the web server to request the files. Now trying to automate those steps in SSIS. NuGet appears to successfully install RestSharp and when coding it appears to resolve all objects referenced from that library in the Script Task component.

Successfully installed 'RestSharp 105.2.3'.
[Screenshot Success Message and resolved objects from library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ii7M8.png)

However, when I save, go back and debug the package, if throws errors that seem to indicate it has not successfully been installed:

```
at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[]
arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)    at     
System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, 
Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)    at 
System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags 
invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
```

When I go back into the Script Task code, the object references are no longer resolving and the reference is indicated as invalid.

I've [found code](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dbrowne/2014/06/25/how-to-load-an-assembly-in-a-ssis-script-task-that-isnt-in-the-gac/) for loading a dll when it can't be loaded to the GAC (I've successfully used that for WinSCPnet.dll -- unrelated to this issue but worked for loading something that also initially returned a similar "unsafe" error), but I'm not sure if that can be used for RestSharp and if so what the syntax would be.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
-Operating System: Windows Server 2012 R2, 64-Bit
-Visual Studio: 2010 .Net Framework 4.5.51650 SP1Rel
-SQLServer 2012 
-Coding in C# 2010
-NuGet Package Manager 2.8.60318.667
```

Comment: Are you combining dlls together with ilmerge? If so, this is a known issue.

Comment: No, I described all the steps I've taken. I've simply tried to use NuGet to load RestSharp. As in the question, it appears to load fine while the Script Task is open as all objects referenced in the library resolve. But when I go back to SSIS it fails (with the message I provided) and when the Script Task is opened again, the references no longer resolve.

Comment: Turn on Fusion logging, and post the log here.  http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsUsingFusionLogViewerToDebugObscureLoaderErrors.aspx

Comment: I'm going to be out of the office for the rest of the week due to a death in the family. I'll try this and log the results when I return. Thank you for your help, @Amy.

Comment: Hi @Amy: I was assigned some other tasks when I returned from the bereavement period so am just getting back to this. I do not believe Fusion logging is loaded on this box (at work -- not something I have a great deal of control over). I've read several articles on how to turn it on and nothing has worked so far -- I searched for fuslogvw.exe on the whole machine and came back with no items matching. Any other suggestions on trouble shooting?